# Pandas get DataFrame with unique column combinations

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'orig': ['ORD', 'AUS', 'AUS'], 'dest': ['LAX', 'JFK', 'JFK']}
```

I'd like to be able to turn that into a `DataFrame` that has two columns `orig` and `dest` that contain all of the unique combinations of `orig` and `dest` in `df` like this:

```
  orig   dest
1 ORD    LAX
2 AUS    JFK
```

so that I can iterate over each row and call a separate method that I've created for each `orig` and `dest`.

Is this possible? Most other answers that I've seen on here don't return a `DataFrame` object.

Comment: Does `df.drop_duplicates()` help?

Comment: Yes that does it. Thanks. I will accept the answer when I can - it's not letting me accept for another 9 minutes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add below code to your code. It will give you dataframe with all unique rows. Please read [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

```
df = df.drop_duplicates()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with drop_duplicates éethod

```
print(df.drop_duplicates())
```